# Inheritance in UIView in Xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, interface-builder

So our problem is how to use inheritance using Xcode.
We have developed BB app. In which we needed a header at every screen. So made a BasicScreen and extended every screen from it.
What we need in Xcode is the same scenario but unluckily we cannot figure out how to role with it.
Can any one suggest us how to implement this or better way to do this...!!
examples or some useful links shared will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What is the problem in creating a superclass with the basic layout (BasicScreen), and make all the following views a subclass of it?

Comment: Too vague. Do you not understand how to subclass any class in Objective-C? Are you unsure of how to draw from a subclass? Have you read [Defining a Custom View](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/CreatingViews/CreatingViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH5-SW23)?

Comment: Okay, people stop down-voting. at that time I was unclear about cocoa api. So if anyone come across this question, please ignore it. *(O boy! I couldn't become a good asker.)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this purpose you need to add header on each view or make a parent view and add subviews in that view below the coordinates of header.

Answer (score 1):

This is not Xcode question. First read about inheritance in Objective C:
http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Objective-C_Inheritance

Second: if you want to use your custom view add the header where this view is declared.

Edit:
 It is probably a good idea to use UIViewController instead of UIView. In this case you can use Interface Builder, that will save you a lot of time and make your code more elegant. Google about that, there are tons of info.